# Did not working after year and a half

Tags: nintendo-dsi

I just found my DSi and I’m trying to charge it, but it is not turning on nor is the light coming up to show it's charging.

Can anyone help? I need it ASAP, as I was going to take it away with me on holiday in 2 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. check your actual outlet by plugging something like a lamp into it. obviously, if nothing happens with the lamp when you try turning *it* on, then that outlet is dead, and you should try another outlet.
2. check your adapter to make sure there are no frayed wires or busted pins in the actual jack.
3. your battery may have hit its limit. unfortunately, i don't think support for the DSi family is available anymore, and you're going to have to buy one off Amazon or something. [luckily for you, Nintendo has released years ago instructions to replace the battery yourself.](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3863/p/696)